# Check if atleast one character is in mysql row, using php

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

i want to check if atleast one character is entered in mysql database.

php:

```
$chk = "SELECT item FROM user WHERE id = '".$name."'";
$rchk = mysqli_query($conn, $chk) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rchk);
if($row['item'] == null){
    $field1 = 'please enter title';
}
```

html bit:

```
<textarea rows='1'cols='10'name='title'wrap='physical'><?php echo"$field1";?></textarea>
```

so if the textarea is empty (no whitespaces) this code works fine, and it will fill up the mysql database with 'please enter title' which would show in the text area automatically. but if i input '   '  (or anything above one space bar) into the field, it does not detect as empty.

i tried using trim, the same thing happens, only detects if no white space is there. also used empty() to no avail.

i figure i would need to detect is there is at least one character in the text field, as i only want the if function to operate if the user inputs no characters into the text field. unfortunately a space does count as a character, so i could i check is there is at least 1 a-z or 0-9 or any symbols.

if function would NOT operate if user inputs 'a', 'ab', 'd!rf', 'a b', 'aert bdjd' etc etc

it would operate if no characters are input for e.g. '', '   ', but not '      a'.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `where ... and length(item) <> 0`?

Comment: If either of the answers helped you please be sure to accept one; if you have questions please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend using a `placeholder` versus inputting actual placholder text into your `textarea`:

```
<textarea placeholder="please enter a title"></textarea>
```

Secondly, I would actually suggest preventing the 'blank string' from being inserted into the database in the first place.

before inserting into the database:

```
trim($value_to_store);
```

If the user inputs a string with just spaces, then they will be trimmed and no value will be inserted.